# How do I setup a TCP over DNS tunnel on Windows?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, tcpip, tunneling, ns-record

I've seen a few guides out there, but I could not get any of them to work. I can point NS records to my domain, so it sounds like I should be able to do this. I tried setting up a DMZ for the server portion, no luck at all.

Comment: please supply more information - "it didn't work" isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Am I the only one who's confused? How do you tunnel the transport layer TCP over the application DNS? Besides the layers being upside down, DNS is usually run over UDP.

Comment: TCP over DNS is a way of getting free internet access if you're on a walled-garden network (e.g. pay wifi hotspot) that otherwise allows DNS queries to work.

Comment: @Alnitak: "it didn't work" is all that I have. There are multiple portions (router settings, domain settings, server portion, client portion, ssh) and all that I know is in the end, I set my browser to point to the proxy and it says the proxy refused the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Java implementation that works on Windows on analogbit.com: [tcp-over-dns](http://analogbit.com/software/tcp-over-dns).

> tcp-over-dns contains a special dns
>   server and a special dns client. The
>   client and server work in tandem to
>   provide a TCP (and UDP!) tunnel
>   through the standard DNS protocol.
>
> This is similiar to the defunct NSTX
>   dns tunelling software. The purpose of
>   this software to is succeed where NSTX
>   failed. For me at least, all NSTX
>   tunnels disconnect within tens of
>   seconds in real world situations.
>   tcp-over-dns was written to be quite
>   robust while at the same time
>   providing acceptable bandwidth speeds.

The programs require the Java runtime environment 6.0+. The server requires admin port 53 access.

There is a nice article from the same author which explains [TCP over DNS](http://analogbit.com/tcp-over-dns_howto) very well.

Comment: the answer would be better without the quote from the tcp-over-dns article, because it's incomplete and doesn't in any way explain the problem...

Comment: @Alnitak you are right. I deleted that section from the answer. I initially thought that many readers aren't familiar with that "technology", so I tried to compensate that. But I didn't want to quote the whole article.

Comment: That guide is the one that doesn't work for me. It doesn't explain what ports I need to open on my home router (just 53?). I even setup DMZ and it didn't work. It says to use SSH to make a proxy, but i'm not sure that most users know what that means. I am pretty sure it means I set my browser to point to localhost:8080 but it still does not work.